# Can a VS Code VSIX record the executable bit on files

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is it possible for a VSIX to record the executable bit on a file (i.e. file mode, linux execute bit) such that when the VSIX is installed, linux/mac will recognize the file is executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because VSIX is simply a ZIP package, your wish comes true as long as 1) everything on disk is set up properly before you run `vsce package` or `vsce publish`, and 2) you run that on macOS or Linux.

The same packaging process just won’t work well on Windows.